# Enabling stemming from sphinx.yml in Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-plugins, thinking-sphinx

I created a config/sphinx.yml file with the line:
morphology: stem_en

After running rake ts:config, it doesn't seem to have changed development.sphinx.conf, and following a rebuild, searching for "dawg" doesn't match "dawgs".

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall correctly the morphology line should fall under a "development" header like so:

```
development:
  morphology: stem_en
```

Not sure if you've done so already, but if not give it a try.

Comment: Yup, config/sphinx.yml expects environment keys for each group of settings.