# How to search for plural/singular of word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am using the Thinking Sphinx gem. Is there a way to configure it so that it includes the plural and singular word in the search results?

For example:
"Dog" will find "Dogs"
"Service" will find "Services"

I believe any search capability should have this sort of action.

Comment: Have a look at word stemming or morphology -> http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology

Comment: For adding individual cases, use `wordforms`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling stemming from sphinx.yml in Thinking Sphinx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173777/enabling-stemming-from-sphinx-yml-in-thinking-sphinx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add morphology to the thinking sphinx yml file.

```
development:
  morphology: stem_en
```